# Alert Dialog has empty RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-alertdialog

I use the following code to display a recycler view in an alert conversation. When calling the method showAlertDialog() a dialog appears on the display, but it is empty. The list that contains the information for the output is not empty, I checked.

```
public class AlertDialogShower  {
private final String LOG_TAG = "AlertDialogShower";
private Context context;

public AlertDialogShower(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public void showAlertDialog(AppInfoListModel appInfoListModel, FragmentManager fragmentManager) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.alert_app_workperiod, null);
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.alert_app_info_list_view);
    AppInfoArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new AppInfoArrayAdapter(appInfoListModel.getAppInfos());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog
            .Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(view.getContext(), R.style.Theme_AppCompat_Dialog));
    builder.setView(view);

    builder.setCancelable(false)
            .setNegativeButton(view.getContext().getString(R.string.cancel_text), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.setTitle(appInfoListModel.getAppPackage());
    alertDialog.show();


}

/**
 * This is a modified adapter for displaying and processing the list of events in listview
 */
public class AppInfoArrayAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AppInfoArrayAdapter.AppViewHolder> {
    ArrayList<AppInfoListModel.AppInfo> appInfoList;

    public AppInfoArrayAdapter(ArrayList<AppInfoListModel.AppInfo>  appList) {
        this.appInfoList = appList;
    }

    @Override
    public AppViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.app_info_list_item, viewGroup, false);
        AppViewHolder appViewHolder = new AppViewHolder(v);
        return appViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(AppViewHolder appViewHolder, int i) {
        appViewHolder.periodDay.setText(appInfoList.get(i).getDate());
        String periods = " ";
        for (String s : appInfoList.get(i).getRunningEvents()){
            periods += s + "\n";
        }
        appViewHolder.timeLaunch.setText(periods);
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return appInfoList.size();
    }

    public class AppViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView periodDay;
        TextView timeLaunch;


        AppViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            periodDay = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.ai_date_tv);
            timeLaunch = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.ai_list_date_tv);

        }
    }
}
```

}

A call is made from another fragment. 
    new 
AlertDialogShower(fragmentView.getContext()).showAlertDialog(appInfo,getFragmentManager());

Comment: set a `LayoutManager` to `RecyclerView`

Answer (score 0):

**You forget to add LayoutManager with RecycleView that's why it's empty.**

> optional

// use this setting to improve performance if you know that changes
// in content do not change the layout size of the RecyclerView

mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

> required

// use a linear layout manager

```
LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
```

Comment: Thanks! It's work. I'm realy forget add layoutManager. Have a nice day, man!